# Failed to start segment instance database sdwXX when I init greenplum

Tags: python, database, postgresql, greenplum

I encounter a problem when I init Greenplum,so I can't install Greenplum successfully.
I have installed Greenplum successfully in VMs which I used bridge mode，during initialization I also encounted a problem which said that it cant copy files between segments(such as sdw1 and sdw2),I find the solution setting the DNS from Internet and then I install Greenplum successfully.
Now I install Greenplum on cloud server in the same way as VMs, and the CentOS have default DNSs but I have tried many times and can't install it successfully,I think the problem is 'Failed to start segment instance database sdwXX',but I don't konw what causes the problem is. Please help me,thank you.
The log is below:

```
20160717:18:34:05:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building the Master instance database, please wait...
20160717:18:34:37:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting the Master in admin mode
20160717:18:34:48:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing parallel build of primary segment instances
20160717:18:34:48:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Spawning parallel processes    batch [1], please wait...
......
20160717:18:34:49:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Waiting for parallel processes batch [1], please wait...
.
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Parallel process exit status
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as completed           = 0
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as killed              = 0
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Total processes marked as failed              = 6 <<<<<
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing parallel build of mirror segment instances
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Spawning parallel processes    batch [1], please wait...
......
20160717:18:34:50:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Waiting for parallel processes batch [1], please wait...
.
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Parallel process exit status
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as completed           = 0
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as killed              = 0
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Total processes marked as failed              = 6 <<<<<
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Errors generated from parallel processes
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Dumped contents of status file to the log file
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building composite backout file
20160717:18:34:52:gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Failures detected, see log file /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/gpinitsystem_20160717.log for more detail Script Exiting!
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Script has left Greenplum Database in an incomplete state
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Run command /bin/bash /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/backout_gpinitsystem_gpadmin_20160717_183346 to remove these changes
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
```

So I see the /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/gpinitsystem_20160717.log ,and a part of content is below:

```
20160717:18:34:51:010213 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010213 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010213 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010710 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010945 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010213 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][0]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw2 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg0
20160717:18:34:51:010710 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010293 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010416 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010945 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010710 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010293 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010416 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010945 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010293 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010710 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010546 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010416 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010945 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010293 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010710 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][4]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw1 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg4
20160717:18:34:51:010546 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010416 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010945 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][5]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw1 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg5
20160717:18:34:51:010293 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][1]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw2 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg1
20160717:18:34:51:010546 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010416 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][2]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw3 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg2
20160717:18:34:51:010546 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:51:010546 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL][3]:-Failed to start segment instance database sdw3 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg3
20160717:18:34:51:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PARALLEL_WAIT
20160717:18:34:51:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PARALLEL_COUNT
20160717:18:34:51:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PARALLEL_SUMMARY_STATUS_REPORT
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Parallel process exit status
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as completed           = 0
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as killed              = 0
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Total processes marked as failed              = 6 <<<<<
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PARALLEL_SUMMARY_STATUS_REPORT
FAILED:sdw2~43000~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg0~8~0~44000
FAILED:sdw1~43000~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg4~12~4~44000
FAILED:sdw1~43001~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg5~13~5~44001
FAILED:sdw2~43001~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg1~9~1~44001
FAILED:sdw3~43000~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg2~10~2~44000
FAILED:sdw3~43001~/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg3~11~3~44001
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function CREATE_QES_MIRROR
INSERT 0 1
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Errors generated from parallel processes
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Dumped contents of status file to the log file
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building composite backout file
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function ERROR_EXIT
20160717:18:34:52:gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Failures detected, see log file /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/gpinitsystem_20160717.log for more detail Script Exiting!
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Script has left Greenplum Database in an incomplete state
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Run command /bin/bash /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/backout_gpinitsystem_gpadmin_20160717_183346 to remove these changes
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160717:18:34:52:022913 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

check that all your environment variables are setup correctly. The segments should have these

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~

Also, please check if you performed gpseginstall before gpinitsystem

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I found the problem and gpinitsystemed successfully.Because of my careless,I made a mistake when coping and pasting and I updated /etc/sysctl.conf on my segment hosts,it worked.